# Once password is entered at login, purple screen and move frozen

Tags: dual-boot

When I enter my password at login Ubuntu freezes on a purple screen.

I reinstalled hoping it would fix but the problem persists.

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with Windows 10 on a MSI GE63VR7RE laptop (i7 / 16GB RAM & GTX 1060).

Any ideas why it freezes?

Answer (score 0):

I did a full install with internet option to download.

The problem was present again but the third login attempt worked, no idea why.

I installed the nvidia drivers using the command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The problem is gone and the system starts ok.